# GUI suddenly slow - GPU utilization 100% - what to do?

Tags: nvidia, gnome, gui, performance

Sometimes my `Ubuntu 22.04` gets noticeably slower. I can see the cursor is moving slower, hovering over icons takes a second or two etc...

I checked all the possible causes that I can think of:

1. CPU load is small
2. 30GB RAM is free
3. Disk load almost 0%
4. **NVIDIA Settings shows GPU Utilization 100%**

I guess that's the issue (4).

`top` output:

[image]

Right now as I'm writing this, only Intellij Ide / PyCharm is running, Slack, Trello, Thunderbird and Firefox.

I have three monitors connected - one 4k and two Full HD.

[image]

What I can do to avoid this (except buying a new GPU)? Is there anything software-wise I can do to prevent it being so slow?

Comment: Close each application, one by one, and check GPU usage between each. Then you know which application to troubleshoot further. Please include your results in question. Thanks.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks, will do that, but it will take some time as it happens "randomly".